# Unable to load php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using `Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15` with PHP `5.6.15` both `32 bit`. I am unable to load `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll`. I have added `extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll ; DLL for SQL SRV` in `php.ini` and also kept the respective DLL in the `ext` directory.

What could be the reason for this?

PS: I downloaded the 32 bit dll file.

Comment: Did you restarted the server?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary Yes.

Comment: What server you are using. please give as much info as possible of the environment you are in.

Comment: looks like an issue with a Path variable.
check this link: https://thommck.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/how-to-add-a-path-to-the-system-variables-in-windows-2008-r2/

Comment: Yes I know that. I was at first writing the same thing but wanted to make sure of other things first.

Comment: @malyy Why is path variable required here?

Answer (score 1):

@malyy Why is path variable required here? 
Indeed, it was just a conclusion. as for your post:

```
I am using Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15 with PHP 5.6.15
I have added extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

Why sqlsrv_55, but not sqlsrv_56 ?

Try to add:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Comment: Yes. I just found that!

Answer (score 1):

Since I am using `php 5.6.*`, the required DLL had to be `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`

Microsoft has a compatibility chart: [here: #Driver Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170(v=sql.105).aspx)