# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

please help me

I am Using
Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit,
IIS 8.5,
SQL Server 2014,
PHP 5.6,
Codeigniter 3.1

Sometimes my website shown a this error "Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found." and when I refresh this page this error not appear

But there is this DLL file in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\ and in php.ini there is this sentence extebsion:php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load php\_sqlsrv\_55\_ts.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888956/unable-to-load-php-sqlsrv-55-ts-dll)

Comment: extebsion:php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll ? Did you mean  `extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` . And are you sure to edit the good `php.ini` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this ext (php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll) as you are using php 5.6. After adding it Restart web server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I change that DLL to php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll but I give this error sometimes yet